# Unchanged snapshot when props are added in jest-emotion

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, emotion

Following is my test file for a button component

```
import React from 'react';
import ds from 'path-to-ds';
import Button from '../Button';

afterEach(cleanup);

/* ------------------------ RENDERING TESTS -------------------------- */
test('render with theme prop', () => {
  const { firstChild } = render(<Button theme={ds}/>).container;
  expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('render without theme prop', () => {
  const { firstChild } = render(<Button />).container;
  expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});


test('passing a different theme object', () => {
  const { firstChild } = render(<Button theme='' />).container;
  expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Now if I add a prop to the first test, like this:

```
test('render with theme prop', () => {
  const { firstChild } = render(<Button someProp theme={ds}/>).container;
  expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

There is **no difference** detected in the snapshot(no error).

I am assuming that the serializer that comes with `jest-emotion` does not check for prop changes(correct me if I am wrong). Is there a way to  serialize the output so that it can highlight the prop differences too?

Stack used for testing:

- jest
- jest-emotion
- react-testing-library

Comment: What's in your snapshots? My guess is that it's just DOM nodes, you shouldn't be able to see the props.

Comment: I believe so......it is just DOM nodes

Comment: That's by design, `render` only returns the DOM. I think I don't understand what you're trying to test here

Comment: In addition to the styles, I also wanted to test if there are any prop changes in the snapshot, which is not possible since the snapshot has DOM nodes....so is there a way that I can generate a snapshot with the styles and the props together?

Comment: No, RTL never renders the props

Comment: Is there a custom serializer which I can add, which can render props in the snapshot?

Comment: I don't think so, RTL doesn't have access to the props. If I were you I wouldn't care about the props, focus on what is rendered